# Flutter: unable to run application on iOS emulator

Tags: firebase, flutter

The code worked fine. As the firebase packages got updated in the pub.dev website, I changed the firebase instances to the new version. After that, I guess the firebase package didn't install properly and threw this error when I ran **flutter run** for the iOS emulator.

```
rishikrishna@Rishikrishnas-MacBook-Pro chat_server % flutter run      
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 11 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                              0.9s
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Finding Podfile changes
      A firebase_storage
      - Flutter
      - cloud_firestore
      - firebase_auth
      - firebase_core
      - image_picker

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
    cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
    firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
    firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
    firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '6.26.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
    -> Fetching podspec for `image_picker` from `.symlinks/plugins/image_picker/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
      performed in repo update
      CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/6.20.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only
      performed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/CoreOnly":
      In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
        Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.20.0)

      In Podfile:
        cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.14.0-2, which depends on
          Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 6.26.0)

    Specs satisfying the `Firebase/CoreOnly (= 6.20.0), Firebase/CoreOnly (~> 6.26.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher
    minimum deployment target.

    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `tap'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:986:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:984:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:410:in `analyze'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:234:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:233:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:156:in `install!'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

Flutter doctor:

```
rishikrishna@Rishikrishnas-MacBook-Pro chat_server % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021, locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    ✗ Android license status unknown.
      Try reinstalling or updating your Android SDK Manager.
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for
      detailed instructions.
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Also, I reinstalled all packages and tried flutter clean.
Open for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Open the `Runner.xcworkspace` in Xcode then clean and build the project and try to re-run.
This works for me. I was facing the same issue.